# OpenCL single work-item VS NDRange kernel on FPGA

Tags: opencl, gpu, fpga, pipeline

I am new to OpenCL and working on block cipher encryption using OpenCL on FPGA. I read some paper and know there are two sorts of kernels in Opencl (single work-item and NDRange).  The functions of NDRange kernel will not be pipelined by the compiler automatically while functions of the single work-item kernel will.

Is it recommended to implement single work-item kernel rather than NDRange kernel 
on FPGA? Why?

If I want to make the kernel run in a loop until reading all the data, then the kernel (fetch some data from host at one time--run on FPGA--write back). How can the pipeline be achieved?

Comment: I recommend checking the guidance from your FPGA vendor. They best know their compiler. I've seen some good videos on their websites too. So not only would you learn the answer to this question, you'd likely learn much more in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Single work-item kernel allows you to move the computation loops into your kernel, and you can generate custom pipelines, Make clever optimizations on accumulations, and control access patterns through "pragmas". An NDRange Kernel relies on you to partition the data among the work-items, and compiler generates SIMD type hardware, each unit described by your kernel. It is good if your problem has a regular data parallelism making partitioning easy. The NDRange kernels of OpenCL are designed for SIMD computation units like GPU. You can also utilize "channels" to move data between single work-item kernels in streaming applications, relieving DRAM bandwidth. For NDRange kernels you would have to use global memory as medium of data sharing between kernels.

Answer (score 1):

Shreedutt's answer  was generally acceptable before ~2016. Intel's pipe and channel implementation go beyond this by quite far:

1. User can have multiple kernels or multiple work-items accessing a pipe if you do not have work-item-variant or dependency on the work-item ID.
2. Deterministic order of access to pipe from multiple work-items (e.g. NDRange kernels) can be controlled and guaranteed: "When pipes exist in the body of a loop with multiple work-items, as shown below, each
   loop iteration executes prior to subsequent iterations. This implies that loop iteration 0 of each work-item in a work-group executes before iteration 1 of each work-item in a work-group, and so on."

   ```
   __kernel void ordering (__global int * data, write_only pipe int __attribute__((blocking)) req)
   {
   write_pipe (req, &data[get_global_id(0)]);
   }
   ```
3. Channels extension is a viable alternative which can be executed in the loop with multiple work-items:

   ```
   __kernel void ordering (__global int * data, int X) {
     int n = 0;
     while (n < X)
     {    
       write_channel_intel (req, data[get_global_id(0)]);
       n++;
     }
   }
   ```
4. There are restrictions and caveats that can be found in section 5 of the UG-OCL002 | 2018.05.23 for channels and pipes. I would suggest a read though it and watch the latest training block https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0RtAKeRl00. Another huge caveat is that the big companies decided to have separate code syntax for OpenCL with requiring different pragmas, one more another less.
5. I should have started however with this IWOCL presentation: https://www.iwocl.org/wp-content/uploads/iwocl2017-kapre-patel-opencl-pipes.pdf. The reason is than these are new compute models and huge performance gains can be attained by properly structuring your parallel application. Even more importantly is to learn how to move and NOT to move data. Check out latest trick GPU on removing transposes: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/tensor-core-ai-performance-milestones/
   We can do more tricks like this in FPGA, can we?

I leave it for the interested readers and contributors to weight in on XILINX OpenCL pipes.

IMHO this is the most important topic for software defined FPGAs since the slices bread, especially if we are to win some races in ML/AI GPUs vs. FPGAs. I am rooting for the FPGA team.